# Displaying Label on Tkinter for a fixed amount of time

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm creating a GUI application in Python 2.7 using Tkinter.
I have this piece of code:

```
vis=Label(pur,text='Purchase Added successfully',font=(8))
vis.place(x=150,y=460)
```

I wanna know if there's any way to display the Label 'Purchase Added Successfully' for a limited amount of time(~3 seconds) and then it would disappear. This is because I'm interested in adding a new 'purchase' after the current one, and don't want the success messages to overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways depending on the project pattern, all based on the syntax :

```
vis=Label(pur,text='Purchase Added successfully',font=(8))
vis.place(x=150,y=460)
vis.after(3000, function_to_execute)
```

**Total Destruction**

If you don't want to wonder whether the label is already created, hidden or empty, and mostly avoid possible memory leaks (thanks to Bryan Oakley comment):

```
vis.after(3000, lambda: vis.destroy() )
```

But then you need to create a fresh new `Label` for every purchase.

---

**Hide and Seek**

The following method allows to disable the display of the Label without destroying it.

```
vis.after(3000, lambda: vis.place_forget() )
#vis.after(3000, lambda: vis.grid_forget() ) # if grid() was used
#vis.after(3000, lambda: vis.pack_forget() ) # if pack() was used
```

Then you can enable it again for the next purchase, with `vis.place(x=150,y=460)`

---

**Text Eraser**

Another way, maybe less interesting, unless you prefer keeping an empty Label in the container widget:

```
vis.after(3000, lambda: vis.config(text='') )
```

(Note that you can replace the text with `vis.config(text='blabla')` for the next purchase)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped!

Comment: `place_forget` merely removes it from display, it doesn't destroy the widget. If you keep creating new labels without destroying the old, you end up leaking memory.