# how can I make a lable showing in tkinter for special time?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I want a lable in tkinter  showing for 5 seconds and then disappear I by default how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in tkinter .after that you can use to destroy a window after a specified amount of milliseconds.

[Displaying Label on Tkinter for a fixed amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745484/displaying-label-on-tkinter-for-a-fixed-amount-of-time)